# Determine probability of finding best path

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We are trying to  transmit a data packet from Point A to point C. There are 3 paths available to transmit it from A to B and 3 paths to transmit from B to C. The paths are chosen based on their signal strength at the time of transmission which follow Exponential distribution: $\frac{1}{\alpha}e^{-x/\alpha}$. Mean value for three paths (black, orange and blue) are $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$.

The signal strength at different paths are random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, X'_1, X'_2, X'_3$

Now, for A to B, we want to select the path that gives the maximum signal strength: $\max(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ and then for B to C, we want to select the same path that is selected for transmission from A to B.

For example, based on given sample signal strength values, we will select path 1 (54) for transmission from A to B and then use the same path for B to C.

[image]

The question is how do I show using analytical derivation for this distribution? I am not looking for detailed answer but a hint how to approach the problem will be great. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry that I might be missing something very obvious...  What is the Raleigh distribution describing?  It's a continuous r.v. so is it describing the transmission time?  And what do you mean by "the probability when transmitting"?  The probability of what event?

Comment: I have updated the question. The signal strength values are drawn from Rayleigh distribution. I want to find the distribution of the event: "When at step 1 the best path is selected and for step 2 the same path is used". The goal is compare this with the approach: "when we are selection the best path at both steps"

Comment: OK, so you get to observe $X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, X_3 = x_3$, and pick the largest $x_i$, i.e. $i = \arg \max x_i$.  Having picked this $i$, you must now use $X'_i$.  What exactly are you trying to calculate?  Something like $E[X_i + X'_i]$?  The whole distribution $X_i + X'_i$?

Comment: The whole distribution and then $E[X_i + X'_i]$. The next step is to find the distribution where we select the path $i = \arg \max (X_i + X'_i)$ and compare between the two methods.

Comment: Interesting...  My first instinct would be you need to condition on $i=1,2,3$, but it's not trivial even after that.  BTW, you say [Rayleigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution), but your PDF formula is actually for the (much simpler?) [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).  Which do you mean?

Comment: Its exponential because we are considering power here. We are measuring SNR (signal to noise ratio) at each path which experiences Rayleigh fading. The theory behind this can be found in: "Wireless Communication" by Rappaport (Chapter 7, Equation: 7.56).